# Trying to scrape site data for embed purposes and CORS is getting in the way?

Tags: angular, http, cors

I'm using Angular I've rewritten this guy's embed library https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed from PHP to typescript. And in his demo http://oscarotero.com/embed3/demo he's able to scrape meta data from sites without a problem. But when I do so using HTTPClient in Angular I get a CORS error. So my question is how do I scrape opengraph, twitter summary card etc. metadata from a different domain without triggering CORS error. Is there something about CURL that allows this guy to bypass that or am I missing something here? any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something about CURL that allows this guy to bypass that or
>   am I missing something here?

Yes, CORS is a browser security feature.  It does not affect CURL.

> So my question is how do I scrape opengraph, twitter summary card etc.
>   metadata from a different domain without triggering CORS error.

Run outside a browser (e.g. Node, CURL, etc.)

Twitter, Opengraph, etc. do not want you creating websites that trick users into making requests against their API so they do not allow this.

Comment: Also, if you're just trying to run this locally.  You can disable CORS on your personal Chrome.  Do this at your own risk: `chrome --disable-web-security` or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US